# Access sql Select From Where SUBSTRING = combobox.value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to state first and foremost that it is my FIRST day experimenting with SQL and I have around 5 hours of experience with access. Consider that any ambiguity in answers WILL be misunderstood.

I have a table with information about projects `[Liste Projets]` with project numbers in field `[Projet AHNS]` and a table with information about documents `[Documents]`, in which the project number to which the document belongs is in field `[ID]`. Each project has several documents, obviously.

Projects are identified with a number such as `H-1234` in `[Liste Projets]![Projet AHNS]` but `_H-1234=567` in `[Documents]![ID]`. I want to have a query that can retrieve all documents from a given project. I started by requesting the document number, in field `[Numéro Document (Sans Page)]`. I wrote:

```
SELECT [Numéro Document (Sans Page)]
FROM [Documents]
WHERE [ID] = "_H-1234=567"
                 ^^ This static example would be replaced by a combobox value when OK
```

This worked somewhat, I got a single document from project H-1234. Unfortunately since projects are referred to by `H-1234` in the combobox I need to put on my regex gloves to remove the unique identifier after the "=" and the underscore so I retrieve ALL the documents. To start out, I tried something like

```
SELECT [Numéro Document (Sans Page)]
FROM [Documents]
WHERE SUBSTRING([ID], 2) = "H-9978=00001"
```

just to see if I can get SUBSTRING working to get rid of the "_". Apparently not, and I can't find information online (maybe I'm searching with the wrong terms). Can anyone help me out? I eventually want to get to

```
SELECT [Numéro Document (Sans Page)]
FROM [Documents]
WHERE SOME_REGEX([ID]) = ComboBoxValue
                  ^            ^- Would contain a string such as H-1234
                  '- ID is like "_H-1234=567"
```

Please write any comments you think of about question clarity, as I could become a regular poster in SQL but I'm not sure if my syntax is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` is not supported in Access.  `Mid` is the Access counterpart of that function.

But I'm not sure you need it here.  Unless I misunderstood the question, you should be able to get what you want with a `Like` comparison ...

```sql
WHERE [ID] Like '_' & [Forms]![YourForm]![YourCombo] & '=*'
```

If you will be running the query from ADO/OleDb, you will need a different wildcard ...

```sql
WHERE [ID] Like '_' & [Forms]![YourForm]![YourCombo] & '=%'
```

Or you can use `ALike` instead of `Like` so the query will work the same in any context without changing the wildcard ...

```sql
WHERE [ID] ALike '_' & [Forms]![YourForm]![YourCombo] & '=%'
```

Comment: AH ok. Coming from a VBA background I changed mid to SUBSTRING specifically because I read online that it was the way to do it in SQL... Also I was using a wildcard '*' after the combo, not a '=*' so it included projects like H=123 with H-1234. Thanks for the full answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  I just remembered `[ID]` will start with a `_`, so updated the answer.  Beware that `_` will be treated as a wildcard matching any single character if you run the query from ADO/OleDb or with `ALike`.  But I'm guessing that will be OK unless you have `[ID]` values which start with some other character and you don't want to match those.

Comment: Yes, I had fixed that myself because it was returning everything. I  also would like to know what the value of my combo is, because i can't seem to get the results I want. `WHERE [ID] Like '_' & [Forms]![f_FeuilleBleue]![ComboBox177] & '=*'` returns nothing even though the value of the combobox should return around 100 documents. I'd like to verify what access thinks I'm querying with the combobox. How can I do that?

Comment: I can't spot the problem.  You can check the combo's value in the Immediate window: `Debug.Print [Forms]![f_FeuilleBleue]![ComboBox177]`  (You can use Ctrl+g to go to the Immediate window.)

Comment: It works perfectly if I remove the = from the second wildcard. Although I believe that puts me at risk of having documents from project H-1234 when i ask for H-123, and I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't understand how the `=` character breaks the match.  This query gives me -1 (True) in both columns: `SELECT '_H-1234=567' Like '_' & 'H-1234' & '=*' AS Expr1, '_H-1234=567' ALike '_' & 'H-1234' & '=%' AS Expr2 FROM Dual;`

Comment: Is your `=` character the plain ASCII 61 character or some Unicode character which looks the same as `=`?

Comment: I managed to fix it. The problem was between the chair and the computer (d'oh!). Although I raise a different question now. The result of this query is a list of docs belonging to the requested project. I want the user to select a drawing from the list, presented in a comboBox (first they select project, then they would select document). I got the document list running fine for the first project, but now when i change the project it doesn't update the document comboBox! How can i make it 'volatile'?

Comment: I would gladly but chat is blocked where I work. Should I make a new question for this?

Comment: OK.  Yes, a new question is probably best.  But first investigate using the After Update event of the project combo to requery the document list combo ... perhaps like this `Me.cboDocList.Requery`

Comment: I put it in a button instead because the AfterUpdate didn't trigger. I don,t think I understand what causes an Update. In any case, i might switch it to a combobox change, I'll look into that. Thanks a million for your help, and I'm glad I met the Siddarth Rout of Access ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
RIGHT(Id,LEN(Id)-1)
```

This takes Len(Id)-1 characters from comboboxValue starting from the end of the value. Len(Id) returns the length of the Id.

Acces supports Left,Right and Mid

So your query would become the following:

```
SELECT [Numéro Document (Sans Page)]
FROM [Documents]
WHERE RIGHT([ID],LEN([ID])-1) = ComboBoxValue
```

Comment: The combobox value is shorter than the info in the field I'm searching. I don't want to cut the combobox (H-1234) I want to cut the field ID (_H-1234=00001). Also comboboxValue is not a variable of any kind, I just wrote that because I will change it to the value of a certain comboBox in my form later on (if this is feasible?).

Comment: I misread your post and made a mistake in the example, updated the answer

Comment: Upvoted for continuity, although I found my answer above. Thanks!